# switch with Strings doesn't compile in Java 7

Tags: ant, java-7

I have a project which used to compile and run fine. However, it complains when I try to use switch with Strings, with a java 7 compiler. I build this project using Ant.

The Ant config file (projectBuilder.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="TutoMigLayout" default="Main" basedir=".">
  <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
  <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
  <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
  <property name="lib.dir" location="lib" />
  <property name="build.dir" location="bin" />

  <!--
    Create a classpath container which can be later used in the ant task
  -->
  <path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <!-- Deletes the existing build directory-->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Creates the  build  directory-->
  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Compiles the java code -->
  <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
  <echo message="Using Java version ${ant.java.version}."/>
    <javac target="1.7" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="true" classpathref="build.classpath" />
  </target>

  <target name="Main" depends="compile">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>

</project>
```

I get this in the console :

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\workspace\TutoMigLayout\projectBuilder.xml
clean:
[delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\workspace\TutoMigLayout\bin
makedir:
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\workspace\TutoMigLayout\bin
compile:

[echo] Using Java version 1.7.
[javac] C:\Users\workspace\TutoMigLayout\projectBuilder.xml:31: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\workspace\TutoMigLayout\bin
[javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.7
[javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[javac] use -help for a list of possible options

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\workspace\TutoMigLayout\projectBuilder.xml:31: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 481 milliseconds
```

When I remove the compiler version from the compile target, I get that instead :

```
[javac] C:\Users\invite01.acensi\workspace\TutoMigLayout\src\components\EqualsAction.java:26: incompatible types
[javac] found   : java.lang.String
[javac] required: int
[javac]         switch(operator) {
[javac]                ^
```

I thought we could switch with Strings in Java 7 ?

If I click run one more time, I get a completely different message :

```
Error : could not find or load the main class test.Test
```

Edit : javac -version
javac 1.6.0_32
OK how do I change that ? I thought setting compiler compliance level to 1.7 and selecting jre7 was enough ?

Comment: `"javac: invalid target release: 1.7"` You are probably compiling with Java 6 or earlier, or you are using a (very) old version of Ant which doesn't allow target 1.7

Comment: from a command line run this: "javac -version".

Comment: javac -version yields javac 1.6.0_32. OK how do I change that ? I thought setting compiler compliance level to 1.7 and selecting jre7 was enough ?

Comment: You need _JDK_ 7, not just _JRE_ 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `source="1.7"` attribute. This controls the language features. However, in most cases both `target` and `source` attributes should be set to the same version. And, as mentioned by others, the compiler must support this version.